# How do you evaluate $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{p}(1-x^{-r})^{\frac{1}{p} - 1}(rx^{-r})dx$ for fixed $p,r > 0$?

Tags: probability, integration

I'm not sure there's a nice elementary solution that only involves standard calculus tricks.

Comment: Change variable to $t = x^{-r}$, the integral becomes a  [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Answer (score 2):

With the substituion that @achille hui suggested we have that $t^{-r}=x$ and $-rt^{-r-1}dt=dx$ so we have that your integral becomes $$\frac{-r^2}{p} \int_1^0 (1-t)^{\frac{1}{p}-1} t^{-r}dt= \frac{r^2}{p} \int_0^1 (1-t)^{\frac{1}{p}-1} t^{-r}dt.$$ Now using the formula for the Beta function found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function we have that, $$\frac{r^2}{p} \int_0^1 (1-t)^{\frac{1}{p}-1} t^{-r}dt =\frac{r^2}{p}B(\frac{1}{p},1-r).$$  You can also go a little further to represent the beta function in terms of gamma functions, this is nice because for positive integer values the gamma function is just the factorial so we have, $$\frac{r^2}{p}B(\frac{1}{p},1-r) =  \frac{r^2\Gamma(\frac{1}{p}) \Gamma(1-r)}{p \Gamma(\frac{1}{p}+1-r)}.$$  The formula to convert a beta function into a gamma function can be found in the wikipedia page I linked.